# Integration MVC application with WordPress using Single Sign On

Tags: wordpress, model-view-controller, single-sign-on

I am trying to integrate WordPress blog with the **MVC application** so that the users logged into the MVC application can access the WordPress blog (like **SSO**).(i.e) the users should able to access WordPress blog with the credentials used for the MVC application.
Previously I have tried with OAuth2 and **DotnetOpenAuth** plug-ins, but I could not make it single sign on. Is there any other way to make SSO with WordPress from MVC.